# .Net 2.0 is not appearing in Visual studio 2010 prerequisites dialog box

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-2.0

I am unable to find .Net 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010 prerequisite dialog box.

[image]

How to add .Net 2.0 prerequisite in visual studio 2010 installer project ?

Comment: Which .NET Framework version have you specified in the Launch conditions?

Comment: I want to specify .Net 2.0. But I can't see in above dialog box.

Comment: .NET 2 support has expired. Everything must be .NET 3.5 SP1 and above.